Cannot create pool in meteora mainnet using mercurial-dynamic-amm-sdk
I am trying to create a pool in meteora mainnet using the createPermissionlessConstantProductPoolWithConfig
but I am getting a Invalid authority to create the pool. But when I tried create pool with createPermissionlessPool I was able to create the pool in mainnet the script I am using as reference is the example script provided in the repo
https://github.com/mercurial-finance/mercurial-dynamic-amm-sdk/blob/master/ts-client/src/examples/create_pool_and_lock_liquidity.ts
Also when I try to create pool with createPermissionlessConstantProductPoolWithConfig in devnet it works
what might be the reason any one know the issue?


This is a guess, but maybe they don't allow permissionless pools on mainnet?
